# dial tcp i/o timeout with HTTP GET request

Tags: go, go-http

Running into some error, I must be overlooking something.
How can I debug this? Dropping connections?

I read the following:
[golang - Why net.DialTimeout get timeout half of the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294052/golang-why-net-dialtimeout-get-timeout-half-of-the-time)
[Go. Get error i/o timeout in server program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185789/go-get-error-i-o-timeout-in-server-program)
[golang get massive read tcp ip:port i/o timeout in ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528060/golang-get-massive-read-tcp-ipport-i-o-timeout-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)
[Locating the "read tcp" error in the Go source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949803/locating-the-read-tcp-error-in-the-go-source-code)
[Getting sporadic "http: proxy error: read tcp: i/o timeout" on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950606/getting-sporadic-http-proxy-error-read-tcp-i-o-timeout-on-heroku)

Error created here:
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b115207baf6c2decc3820ada4574ef4e5ad940ec/src/net/net.go#L179

Goal:
Send a Get request to a url.
Expected result:
return body in JSON.
Encountered problem:
I/O timeout

It works in Postman
Edit:
I added a modified timeout...

Edit2: traced error

Postman request:

```
GET /v2/XRP-EUR/candles?interval=1h HTTP/1.1
Host: api.bitvavo.com
```

Postman Result (1440 rows):

```
[
    [
        1609632000000,
        "0.17795",
        "0.17795",
        "0.17541",
        "0.17592",
        "199399.874013"
    ],
    [
        1609628400000,
        "0.17937",
        "0.18006",
        "0.17622",
        "0.17852",
        "599402.631894"
    ],
    [
        1609624800000,
        "0.18167",
        "0.18167",
        "0.17724",
        "0.17984",
        "579217.962574"
    ],.....
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://api.bitvavo.com/v2/XRP-EUR/candles?interval=1h"
    method := "GET"

    client := &http.Client {
    }
    client.Timeout = time.Second * 60
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

result:

```
Get "https://api.bitvavo.com/v2/XRP-EUR/candles?interval=1h": dial tcp 65.9.73.10:443: i/o timeout
```

Comment: The application works for me.  There's a problem with your local environment or the server is refusing connections from your IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local environment, firewall not allowing golang to dial tcp..
It still allowed the url to be resolved to an ip though (DNS)

Solution:
Change firewall settings on the host to allow the application to connect or temporarily switch off the firewall to test,
Check Docker/kubernetes/reverse proxy settings

Comment: So? What is the proposed solution, change firewall setting locally?

Comment: Open up the firewall to prevent it from blocking this request

Answer (score 6):

I was with this issue when building inside docker containers.

Not sure why, but after a docker `swarm leave --force` and a `systemctl restart docker` the build worked.

Comment: For me, `systemctl restart docker` was enough to fix the problem.